# How do I post information to a server when a link is clicked?

Tags: php, database, ajax, post

Alright so I want my users to be able to click a link that will allow them to add a movie to their favourite.

So in example I have http://xxx.com/favorite.php?userid=1&movieid=1020

For the moment all works well, it adds the values into database, but since it's movies, I do not wish the page to reload, hence the use of Ajax which I am new to.

I worked a little bit around with the different ways of doing it, but never succeeded.

I got alot of help earlier on with my PHP issue, and that would be awesome if it could be the same now!

Basicly just click the favorite image (which is a link) and when the action of posting to database is done, well show another image.

Well I tried many ways, including the JSON ones, but I know GET method can be vulnerable, but it uses session + more security so I'm pretty sure it safe for the moment, I can always work on that later.

Although I'd like to know a nice way with a good example, because I still didn't figured it out.

Thanks to answers tho! Appreciated.

Edit:

Or if not, what would be the best way to POST the info it that's easier? Best way I found is get, since I'm not that advanced in AJAX / etc

Also in my favorite.php file, the information are being submitted to the server, that is the whole point.

Comment: Where's this other image coming from?

Comment: Oh I'm just using small 32x32 icons to display a heart (for the add to favorite) and after I'll display a thumbs up or something. But if that's too complicated, it can just be text.

Comment: Sidenotes: (1) Never user GET's for manipulation if you can avoid it. Prefetching & bots are a bane. GET for retrieval / filtering, POST for manipulation (add, update, delete). (2) What would happen if I go to the url http://example.com/favorite.php?userid=200&movieid=1020? Does user 200 get an uninvited favorite?

Comment: No it checks that the user is logged in, and only his user ID can post, if not it just redirect him to the main page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get JQuery and install it in your web app (see their getting started docs).  In your HTML you'll have:

```
<div id="fav_12_345"><a href="javascript:void(null)" id="addfav">Favorite</a>
```

And in your javascript:

```
$("a#addfav").onclick(function(ev) {
    data_id = $(ev).parent.id();
    $.post('someurl', { data_id: data_id }, function(res) {
        // this bit gets run once the call has been processed on the server
        if (res) {
            // update the new image
            $("img#blah").attr("src", 'someurl');
        }
       }, 'json');
 });
```

And in your PHP

```
$data_id = your_sanitise_user_input($_REQUEST['data_id']);
$data = explode('_', $data_id);
$sql = "UPDATE table set fav_id=$data[1] where id=$data[0]";
$res = your_sql_lib_thing($sql);
print "{res: '$res'}";
```

All this code is approximate and syntactically flawed probably but gives you the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to get data you can use jQuery's .getJSON method http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/, or if you're wanting to post data you can use its .post() method http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Also, if you're just wanting to get html you can use .load() http://api.jquery.com/load/